# Remove duplicate values in googlesheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

How to **remove duplicate values** in google sheet horizontally.
If the values are repeating, how can I remove them and keep one value only.

1. *Keep first value only, and remove the 2nd value that is duplicate* in all the given spreadsheet. There are duplicate values as show horizontally, how to remove them all

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can try `UNIQUE()` and `FLATTEN()` like below-

```
=UNIQUE(FLATTEN(B2:D5))
```

[image]